# Why the lines on the chart have the different start point?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to compare two pandas columns on the chart. They have the same length (18 numbers).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data for plotting
t = range(1, 19)
q3 = data['Q3'].tolist()
q2= data['Q2'].tolist()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(t, q2, q3)

ax.set(xlabel='# Product', ylabel='Mean in %',
       title='Results difference')
ax.grid()

plt.show()
```

And so on the output I see that somehow the q2 result is slightly moved by one x-tick to the left.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `ax.plot(t, q2, q3)` will plot `q2` on the y-axis with `t` as x-axis. And `q3` also on the y-axis, but without an explicit x-axis. When none is given, the default is to use 0,1,2,... as x-axis.

To use `t` both for `q2` and for `q3`, call it as `ax.plot(t, q2, t, q3)`.

The following example shows the difference:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(1, 19)
q2 = np.random.randint(2, 10, 18)
q3 = np.random.randint(2, 10, 18)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

axs[0].plot(t, q2, q3)
axs[0].set_title("plot(t, q2, q3)")
axs[1].plot(t, q2, t, q3)
axs[1].set_title("plot(t, q2, t, q3)")
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]